# How do you find the first index of multiple 'motifs' in a sequence?

Tags: julia

I'm learning Julia, but have relatively little programming experience outside of R. I'm taking this problem directly from rosalind.info and you can find it [here](http://rosalind.info/problems/subs/) if you'd like a bit more detail.

I've given two strings: a motif and a sequence where the motif is a substring of the sequence and i'm tasked with finding out the index of the beginning position of the substring however many times it is found in the sequence.

For example:

Sequence: "GATATATGCATATACTT"

Motif: "ATAT"

ATAT is found three times, once beginning at index 2, once at index 4, and once at index 10. This is assuming 1-based indexing. So the final output would be: **2 4 10**

Here's what I have so far:

```
f = open("motifs.txt")
stream = readlines(f)

sequence = chomp(stream[1])
motif = chomp(stream[2])

println("Sequence: $sequence")
println("Motif: $motif")

result = searchindex(sequence, motif)
println("$result")

close(f)
```

My main problem seems to be that there isn't a searchindexall option. The current script gives me the first index of the first time the motif is encountered (index 2), i've tried a variety of for loops that haven't ended in much success so i'm hoping that someone can give me some insight on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one solution with while loops:

```
sequence = "GATATATGCATATACTT"
motif = "ATAT"

function find_indices(sequence, motif)
    # initalise empty array of integers
    found_indices = Array{Int, 1}()

    # set initial values for search helpers
    start_at = 1

    while true
      # search string for occurrence of motif
      result = searchindex(sequence, motif, start_at)

      # if motif not found, terminate while loop
      result == 0 && break

      # add new index to results
      push!(found_indices, result-1+start_at)
      start_at += result + 1
   end

   return found_indices
end
```

This gives what you want:

```
>find_indices(sequence, motif)
2
4
10
```

Comment: This worked great. So you essentially make the searchindex start at different indexes so it doesn't always go back to index 1 right?

This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @System, yes. That's exactly what it does. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: The function can be made simpler and faster, by using the 3 argument form of `searchindex`, so no slicing is needed. I.e. `searchindex(sequence, motif, start_at)` Also, a typical Julia idiom would be to have `result == 0 && break`.  The while loop should just be `while true`, and no need to even set `result` before the loop.   The increment can be `start_at += result + 1`.  A stylistic issue, would normally have just `found_indices` as the last line, or `return found_indices`, the extra parens are not needed.  Still, it's a worthwhile answer.

Comment: @ScottJones Thanks for the tips. It's always good to learn from someone with more experience. I updated my answer to reflect your advice. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I just realized it can be made even simpler, i.e.: `function find_indices(sequence, motif)
    # initialize empty array of integers
    found_indices = Vector{Int}()

    # set initial position for search helpers
    pos = 0

    # loop until no more occurences of motif are found
    while (pos = searchindex(sequence, motif, pos += 1)) != 0
 push!(found_indices, pos) # add new index to results
    end
    found_indices
end
` (Don't know how to insert a block of code in a comment! :-( )

Answer (score 1):

If the performance is not so important, regular expression can be a good choice.

```
julia> map(x->x.offset, eachmatch(r"ATAT", "GATATATGCATATACTT", true))
3-element Array{Any,1}:
  2
  4
 10
```

PS. The third arguments of `eachmatch` means "overlap", don't forget to set it true.

If a better performance is required, maybe you should spend some time implementing an algorithm like [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).